# One word/phrase describing hostel and mess management

Tags: phrase-requests

I am currently involved in a project, where the system is required by an educational institute for **managing students' hostel fees, hostel stay and mess charges.**
I am looking a *suitable title* for the project.

> I seek a word/phrase that reflects **students' stay in a hostel and its management** 
>   (or)
>    **management and/or disclosure of related information.**

Comment: Dormitory Management System?

Comment: Your question in its present state is inchoate. We need more information about the purpose of your project. Is it to provide a ledger in chart form; you know, column #1 is student's name; colum #2 is "dates of stay"; column #3 is room charges; column #4 is mess charges? If so, the title of the project could be "Hostel-Student Ledger."

Comment: @DamkerngT. helpful, but I need something that describes the project as a whole, in a broader sense apart from just the information system, e.g. a tactical management project(which also involves the stakeholders), may be named "PROJECT MANEUVER, tactics for managing"

Comment: @rhetorician True, but I think, with the title  I want to reflect more than just a ledger. A Ledger of that type would just be a part of the entire project. So I basically need a title that reflects the actual physical facilities and people involved.

Comment: I guess the term *Dormitory Management* (or *Student Hostel Management*, based on rhetorician's comment) is appropriate enough. Instead of talking about *Management Information System*, we talk about *Management System*, which can cover other activities than just the information management alone.

Comment: Assuming someone has commissioned you to complete this project, why not ask him/her to explain in a cogent sentence or two what s/he is after? In your shoes, I wouldn't assume I know what is expected of me; rather, I would put the onus on the person who is giving me the assignment to provide at least a working title for it. That should clarify things for you. If s/he has difficulty summarizing the project "in a nutshell," at least get an overall purpose for it, or perhaps a list of what rubrics should be included.

Comment: @rhetorician I do have a thorough requirements specification for the target system. I just need some word/phrase that describes "students' stay and mess facility", you know so as to call it a project related to that.

Comment: The first part is the "room", the mess facility is usually known as "board" (from table). Collectively, it is "[room and board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_and_board)"

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks... That is something I was locking for...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch some more idiomatic expressions like that would be more helpful...

Comment: @RohanShah Idioms for "room and board"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch NO. obviously no... I meant Idioms expressing a situation like that. Like those that, describe the situation of management, disclosure of information, students hostel stay, management of fees/ mess charges etc...

Comment: I'm not sure there is an idiom for that... are you looking for synonyms around "invoice management systems" and "hospitality billing"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It would fancy some idiomatic expression, but some synonym or some distinctive word describing the meaning of, any of the words from my previous comment will also do.

Comment: "Hostelity" would be an amusing word to coin.

Answer (score 0):

Your system appears to be a "[room and board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_and_board)" invoice management system. On check-in, each "guest" is given a copy of the "[fee schedule](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/fee+schedule)". A running total is kept in the system (this is the "[tab](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tab)"), and printed on "[check-out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/check-out)". At that time, the guest is given an "itemized bill" (or [invoice](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/invoice)) to pay.

Comment: I am clear about my system. It IS "Hostel fees and mess charges management system". I just need some word/phrase that describe such situation and can be used as a title of the project. I mean like "ROOM AND BOARD", are there any other suggestions??

Comment: Invoice Management System. Billing System. System of Record. What you are billing is largely immaterial. You are "billing" them.

Comment: There is no bill, students pay monthly charges for the mess and semester wise fees for the hostel.

Comment: There is a bill; it's monthly for the "board" and semester for the "room".

Comment: again, just need the word/words/phrase/phrases describing one of these: the situation of management, disclosure of information, students hostel stay, management of fees/ mess charges etc... So doesn't matter if there is a bill...

Comment: "fee schedule" and "fee schedule disclosure" are two of the terms... and I've already said them above.